# Loop through the dataframe row using the dictionary keys and output the value when there is a match

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

Dictionary -

```
theDict = {'Apple': '50',
           'Mango': '70',
           'Banana': '20'}
```

Data Frame -

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
         'var1':['Apple','Papaya','Banana'],
          'var2':['Papaya','Mango','Apple'],
         'var3':['Banana','Guava','Grapes']})
```

If the dictionary item, for example Apple is present in the dataframe row, then the output should be a new column with value 50.

If there are two fruits, for example, Mango and Apple in a row then the output should be 50 + 70 in front of that row

Output Sample -

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
         'var1':['Apple','Papaya','Banana'],
          'var2':['Papaya','Mango','Apple'],
         'var3':['Banana','Guava','Grapes']
          'Output_var':['50','50+70','20']})
```

Creating a dataframe with value True or False if the value is present or not

```
m = df.isin(theDict)
print (m)
```

Now not sure, how to loop the dataframe and create a new column.

Any other approach is welcomed!

I was thinking of converting the dataframes to numpy array and use the loop, but my dataset is very big and not sure whether it is an optimal way of doing it

Comment: When you say _the output should be 50 + 70_, are you referring to the value of that expression?

Comment: @AMC i was confused by that too, but he may have strings that he just wants to join, he can always eval or use solution below by Erfan and myself

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have strings that I want to join, the values are not always numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we use `melt` to un-pivot your data to rows.

Then we use `Series.map` to map your dictionary to the fruits.

Finally we use `GroupBy.sum` and `join`:

```
dfm = df.melt('id', ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])
dfm['Output_var'] = dfm['value'].map(theDict).astype(float)
df = df.set_index('id').join(dfm.groupby('id')['Output_var'].sum()).reset_index()

   id    var1    var2    var3  Output_var
0   1   Apple  Papaya  Banana        70.0
1   2  Papaya   Mango   Guava        70.0
2   3  Banana   Apple  Grapes        70.0
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is to just to map along your axis using apply which now accepts the `axis` argument.

```
df['vals'] = df.select_dtypes("object").apply(lambda x: x.map(theDict), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(
    int
).sum(axis=1)

   id    var1    var2    var3  vals
0   1   Apple  Papaya  Banana    70
1   2  Papaya   Mango   Guava    70
2   3  Banana   Apple  Grapes    70
```

if you just want to join the values:

```
df['vals'] = df.select_dtypes("object").apply(lambda x: x.map(theDict), axis=1).stack(0).groupby(
    level=0
).agg("+".join)

print(df)
   id    var1    var2    var3   vals
0   1   Apple  Papaya  Banana  50+20
1   2  Papaya   Mango   Guava     70
2   3  Banana   Apple  Grapes  20+50
```

Comment: Nice way of aggregating everything into one line, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace` and generator expresion (or list comprehension) with `pd.to_numeric` on each column. Finally, call `sum` on output of generator expression

```
cols = ['var1', 'var2','var3']
df['output_var'] = sum(pd.to_numeric(col, errors='coerce').fillna(0) 
                                for col in map(df.replace(theDict).get, cols))

In [27]: df
Out[27]:
   id    var1    var2    var3  output_var
0   1   Apple  Papaya  Banana        70.0
1   2  Papaya   Mango   Guava        70.0
2   3  Banana   Apple  Grapes        70.0
```